# Can i trust echo result of nc command for UDP?

Tags: netcat, udp

**Context :**
I want to test UDP port with nc command

**What happens :**
nc command return nothing on output and 0 when i put `echo $?`

**Which command :**

```
nc -vzu <ip> <port>
echo $?
```

**What is the problem :**
I would like to know if i can trust the result of `echo $?`

**Version :**

- netcat : 0.7.1-5.ph3.x86_64 (on vCenter).
- tcpdump-uw : version 4.9.1-PRE-GIT_2017_09_22

**My thought :**

I know that UDP doesn't verify the packets.

I have tried `echo "something" | nc -vu <ip> <port>` and `tcpdump -i vmk0 -en udp` on destination server but i received nothing.

I think UDP packets is send successfully but it never reach the destination.

What do you think ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your version, but in my case, if it succeeds it will write something such as `Connection to <ip> <port> port [udp/*] succeeded!` and exits with 0, and if it fails it doesn't write anything and exits with 1. I suggest to check what happens if it succeeds; On another shell start `nc -lu <some port>` to listen to some UDP port, and on another try to use `nc` to connect to this port. Then check on the listening side if it succeeded, and on the sending side check if it writes something, and what the exit status is.

Comment: Also try to connect to non-exiting udp port, to check what's the exit status when you know it failed, if it's indeed 0 or 1.

Comment: Hello @aviro,

For the version it's VCenter VM. The netcat version is for Photon OS.
I have tried your method but it doesn't work.

The test vCenter -> ESXI have nothing on output for UDP but the test ESXI -> vCenter works (it have the same output of you).

Comment: I have tried with non-existing udp port on vCenter -> ESXI and it's return 1 code with "Error: Invalid port specification: 650000".
FIY, the TCP test on vCenter -> ESXI return an output.

Comment: valid UDP ports are at the range of 4096-65535. You should choose a non-existent port in that range in order to properly make the test.

Comment: Sorry, i have miss understand your request.
I have re-test for real non used port and i have 0 too : "nc -vzu <ip> 6392" "echo $?" "0".

Comment: So there's your answer. You cannot trust the exit status of your specific version of `nc`.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was afraid of :(
Thank you for your answer and for your patience with me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different `nc` versions or implementations might display different behaviors. You will need to test the specific behavior of your specific `nc` command in order to understand it and determine if you can trust the results.

For instance, with my `nc` version, when I try to connect to some open UDP port, it writes:

```
$ nc -vzu <ip> <port>; echo exit status is: $?
Connection to <ip> <port> port [udp/*] succeeded!
exit status is: 0
```

And returns an exit status of **0**.

But when I try to connect to a port that nothing listens to, it just returns exit status of **1**.

```
$ nc -vzu <ip> <port>; echo exit status is: $?
exit status is: 1
```

In order to determine if you can trust the exit status of your specific `nc` command, try to connect to a closed UDP port. Please notice that valid UDP ports are at the range of **4096-65535**.

In [your case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741227/can-i-trust-echo-result-of-nc-command-for-udp/741426#comment1408412_741227), as you've reported, when you tried to connect a **closed UDP port** in the valid range, your `nc` command returned an exit status of **0** (success), which means that you cannot trust the exit status of your specific version/implementation of `nc`.